# How do I change the default change event reload option?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

JQueryMobile 1.4 is auto-enhancing my anchor links and fetching their content through AJAX. In some cases, I would like for these anchor links to cause a reload if the link is to the same page the user is currently on. If I controlled the call to changePage, then I could specify reloadPage = true, but JQueryMobile doesn't seem to expose this option for enhanced anchors. I tracked down this logic to these lines in the load function of pagecontainer:

```
_loadDefaults: {
    [...]
    // DEPRECATED
    reloadPage: false,

    reload: false,
[...]

settings = $.extend( {}, this._loadDefaults, options ),
[...]
settings.reload = settings.reloadPage;

[...]

// If the content we are interested in is already in the DOM,
// and the caller did not indicate that we should force a
// reload of the file, we are done. Resolve the deferrred so that
// users can bind to .done on the promise
if ( content.length && !settings.reload ) {
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/pagecontainer.js

How do I change _loadDefaults? The object isn't underneath $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer.

This works if I manually update reloadPage to true in JQM source. I am just looking for how I can do the same without modifying JQM source. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `reload` works with URL only. As of jqm 1.4 it's not part of `.options` object.

Comment: You can easily create a custom function, `function reLoad(url) { $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", url, { reload: true }); }`. Call it, `reLoad("page.html");`.

Comment: Hi Omar, Yes, I was hoping to avoid having to modify the anchor links, but perhaps this is the only way. Thanks! If you put this as an answer, I will accept it.